# Forbidden localhost error and error establishing database

Tags: installation, localhost, local-installation

Hi new to Wordpress development and i'm on a mac.

I'm just downloaded MAMP and is using the MAMP Pro trial to run the servers, I've not changed anything, just installed the software and running the servers. I went to http://localhost:8888/phpMyAdmin/ and created a database wpdemo

Then i've downloaded Wordpress and dropped it in the MAMP/htdocs folder, I can access the Wordpress installation using http://localhost:8888/wpdemo/ (I can't access the localhost:8888 though, it says 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.) I went through all the steps in the WP installation guide, and after trying to create a database of name wpdemo, i get this message:

Error establishing a database connection

This either means that the username and password information in your wp-config.php file is incorrect or we can’t contact the database server at localhost. This could mean your host’s database server is down.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  This doesn't seem to be a WordPress issue but a software issue on your Mac with MAMP.  I would suggest going to SO or ask on apple.se.

Comment: Installing WordPress Locally on Your Mac With MAMP: https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_Locally_on_Your_Mac_With_MAMP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try restarting the services.

If you still get the error of Error establishing a database connection, open wp-config.php and check if you have entered the proper database details (username, password, database name, host)